# Why XPATH can't access to the value of this tag? (in Java)

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, jdom

I am pretty new in **XPATH** and I have the following problem:

I have the following snippet of code that seems not work as I expect:

```
                String XML = cdataContent;

                // Crea un nuovo documento XML a partire dal contenuto della
                // precedente sezione CDATA:
                documentXML = builder.build(new StringReader(XML));

                System.out.println(documentXML.toString());
                System.out.println("CDATA Content in XML document:");
                org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter xmlOutputterCDATAContent = new org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter(
                        org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());
                xmlOutputter.output(documentXML, System.out);

                // Crea una nuova query XPATH per selezionare il valore del tag id e lo mette dentro l'oggetto AuthResponse:
                xPath = XPath.newInstance("/root/status/id");
                objectElement = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(documentXML);
                System.out.println("Y " + objectElement.getValue() + " Y");
                authResponse.setStatusResponse(objectElement.getValue());

                // Crea una nuova query XPATH per selezionare il valore del tag message: e lo mette dentro l'oggetto AuthResponse:
                XPath xPathMessage = XPath.newInstance("/root/status/message");
                Element objectElementMessage = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(documentXML);
                System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + objectElementMessage.getValue() + " /MESSAGE");
                authResponse.setStatusResponse(objectElementMessage.getValue());
            }
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is the content of the **documentXML** variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <status>
    <id>-1</id>
    <message>Login o password errate</message>
  </status>
</root>
```

I print it by this lines of the previous code:

```
org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter xmlOutputterCDATAContent = new org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter( org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());
xmlOutputter.output(documentXML, System.out);
```

Now I have to create 2 **XPATH query**: the first have to take the value of the **id** tag (in this case the **-1** value) and the second that have to take the value inside the **message** tag (in this case the string value **"Login o password errate"**)

Ok, as you can see in the posted snipped I have do:

1) **XPATH QUERY TO OBTAIN THE id tag VALUE:**

```
xPath = XPath.newInstance("/root/status/id");
objectElement = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(documentXML);
System.out.println("Y " + objectElement.getValue() + " Y");
```

This query seems to work well because in the Eclipse console is printed:

**Y -1 Y**

(So I know that the -1 value is taken properly)

2) **XPATH QUERY TO OBATIN THE message tag VALUE:**

Then I do:

```
XPath xPathMessage = XPath.newInstance("/root/status/message");
Element objectElementMessage = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(documentXML);
System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + objectElementMessage.getValue() + " /MESSAGE");
```

And now happen something strange because, in the Eclipse console, print the following output:

**MESSAGE: -1 /MESSAGE**

and not **MESSAGE: Login o password errate /MESSAGE** as I expect (because this is the value inside the message tag)

Why? What am I missing? What can I do to solve this situation?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 XPath xPathMessage = XPath.newInstance("/root/status/message");
 Element objectElementMessage = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(documentXML);
```

change it to

```
XPath xPathMessage = XPath.newInstance("/root/status/message");
Element objectElementMessage = (Element) xPathMessage.selectSingleNode(documentXML);
```